# Change of probability measure and back again

Tags: probability-theory

In an example of Shreve, he begins with a random variable $X\sim N(0,1)$ under a measure $\mathbb{P}$ and defines a variable $Y = X+\theta$ and sets $Z = e^{-\theta X - \frac{1}{2}\theta^{2}}$ to define a new measure

$$\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}(A) = \int_{A}Z(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$

for all $A\in \mathcal{F}$ and shows that $Y$ is standard normal. In an exercise at the end of the chapter, he explains that $X$ is related to $Y$ and if you take $\hat{Z} = e^{\theta Y-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}} = 1/Z$ and define

$$\hat{\mathbb{P}}(A) = \int_{A}\hat{Z}(\omega)d\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}(\omega)$$
for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$, he uses this to ask you to show that $\hat{\mathbb{P}} =\mathbb{P}$.

However, to show $\mathbb{P} = \hat{\mathbb{P}}$ I think it depends on the following equation (1) to make sense :

$$\hat{P}(A) = \int_{A}\hat{Z}d\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}(\omega) = \int_{A}\hat{Z}Zd\mathbb{P}(\omega) \quad (1)$$

but I cannot figure out whether or not I can do this. Earlier in the change of measure section, he references another book he authored that I do not own and uses it as the basis for writing

$$Z(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\omega) =\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}(\omega)\quad (2)$$

which I think is supposed to be used as a non-rigorous mnemonic to help manipulate equations like (1).

My question is then, is what I wrote for equation (1) correct? If it is correct, how might I justify it? Can (2) be informally viewed as a change of variables formula of some kind in a manner that is reminiscent of how people manipulate $dy/dx$ in differential equations or things like $dW_{t}dt = 0$ in the quadratic variation of Brownian Motion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\nu$ is a another measure on $(X,\mathcal{E})$ with density $g$ with respect to $\mu$, i.e.
$$
\nu(A)=\int_A g\,\mathrm d\mu,\quad A\in\mathcal{E},
$$
for some non-negative measurable function $g$, then
$$
\int f\,\mathrm d\nu=\int fg\,\mathrm d\mu
$$
for integrable $f$.

To show this, just note that this obviously holds when $f=\mathbf{1}_B$ for any Borel set $B$, and then the result follows using standard arguments in measure theory.

The notation $Z(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\tilde{\mathbb{P}}(\omega)$
is shorthand notation for saying that $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ has density $Z$ with respect to $\mathbb{P}$. Another common notation for this is
$$
\frac{\mathrm d \tilde{\mathbb{P}}}{\mathrm d\mathbb{P}}(\omega)=Z(\omega).
$$

Comment: I am not very familiar with measure theory. In some of the proofs in this text, he uses a method he calls "the standard machine" by proving the statement for indicator functions, then simple functions, positive borel measurable functions and finally for general borel measurable functions. Is this the standard argument you are referring to that I should use?

Comment: Exactly. This argument is very often used when you want to show that some property holds for a large class of functions.

Comment: Ah, this was very useful. I should be able to take it from here. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome.